# Fill current rows with default cells when adding new columns to the table

Tags: javascript, jquery

i create a HTML table and add Rows and Columns on a button event.
This is my code:

```
 function AddColumnToDataTable(){
      $('#tableHeader').append("<th> Header </th>").attr("contenteditable", true);
// Add a new ColumnHeader and set the property "editable"
    }
    function AddRowToDataTable(){
      var count = $('#tableHeader').find("th").length;
// Get the count of Columns in the table

      var newRow = $('#tableBody').append("<tr></tr>");
// Add a new Row

      for(var i = 0; i < count ; i++){
          newRow.find('tr').last().append("<td> Content </td>").attr("contenteditable", true);
// Fill the cells with a default text and set the property "editable"
      }
    }
```

So i want to set new Cells in the older Rows when a new column is added. To make the rows fill themselves with the default text automatically.

Do i have to count the index?
I have x columns, in row y z cells are set, fill the missing ones.. ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I fail to understand the problem. I see you append the new column in header, but not in the rows. Maybe that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, you need to add the new column in the present rows also right?

Then something like this should do the trick (if I didn't understood right pls. comment so I can delete or update my answer):

```js
function AddColumnToDataTable() {
      $('#tableHeader').append("<th>Header</th>").attr("contenteditable", true); // Add a new ColumnHeader and set the property "editable"

      $('#tableBody').find("tr").each(function() {
          $(this).append('<td>Content</td>');
      });
 }

function AddRowToDataTable(){
      var count = $('#tableHeader').find("th").length;
// Get the count of Columns in the table

      var newRow = $('#tableBody').append("<tr></tr>");

      for(var i = 0; i < count ; i++){
          newRow.find('tr').last().append("<td>Content</td>").attr("contenteditable", true);
// Fill the cells with a default text and set the property "editable"
      }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="tableHeader"><th>Header</th></tr>
  <tbody id="tableBody">
  </tbody>
</table>

<input onclick="AddColumnToDataTable();" type="button" value="Column" />
<input onclick="AddRowToDataTable();" type="button" value="Row" />
```

Comment: Sorry this didnt work. I cant tell you what crashed but after using your code, my "AddRow" function started to work only when i first press add row and then add column. After adding the column it added the row too. Weird. But i made a picture of my problem, you can see it here: http://imgur.com/a/nEpBQ

Comment: Added as snippet. Isn't this the behavior you want? If it doesn't add rows until you add the first column my first guess is you have some invalid markup somewhere. Since you didn't post the markup I posted the one I had in mind when I posted the answer. (Click the Run code snippet button).